# HBase makes regions ignoring the established configuration

Tags: size, hbase, region

I'm using HBase 0.98. 
In the `hbase-site.xml` I didn't set the split policy nor the max file size for the regions. The default values are used: 10GiB (`10737418240`) for the `MAX_FILESIZE` attribute and `IncreasingToUpperBoundRegionSplitPolicy` for the `SPLIT_POLICY`.

When writing a table, all this make sense. I write the original table without any configuration. I just created it with:

> create 'raw', 'c1'

When the dump was finished the regions were these:

> 310 /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/.tabledesc
>
> 0 /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/.tmp
>
> 3.4 G /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/0af75fec94d251fcb576059caad679d3
>
> 505.5 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/2713fccb2da4d0fcadc9c57bb23dc388
>
> 505.5 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/4b413063bc1f31d475129ce5abd730d2
>
> 115.4 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/b7ee08d6d7540b2b1bdf98c67c00cd77
>
> 973.5 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/raw/bfcd8222b95814893516c358e8d97a1f

After that, I decided to dump the whole table in other table in order to get around 8 regions.

I created a table through hbase shell with this command:

> create '8reg', {METHOD => 'table_att', CONFIGURATION => {MAX_FILESIZE => '738197504', 'SPLIT_POLICY' => 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy'}}, {NAME => 'c1'}

So the `MAX_FILESIZE` attribute is overriden with 704MiB and the `SPLIT_POLICY` with `ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy`. However, when writting the new table, the behavior is similar. I don't get anything similar to what I expected. Some regions exceed the `MAX_FILESIZE`. It seems that HBase is using again the default configuration (10GiB and IncreasingToUpperBoundRegionSplitPolicy):

> 393 /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/8reg/.tabledesc
>
> 0 /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/8reg/.tmp
>
> 692.2 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/8reg/4bf7246cc65dfa63f2f8d9773f49fb56
>
> 3.7 G /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/8reg/67ed89ae43a31a78284514c925109826
>
> 1023.4 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/8reg/904224f3a5c5f427f5fe22665fb16a29
>
> 68.0 M /user/hadoop/hbase-datastore/data/default/8reg/d2c36e9e9a35665add3b13265d80ae09

The description of the original table is:

> DESCRIPTION ENABLED 'raw', {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {MAX_FILESIZE => ' true 10737418240'}, {NAME => 'c1', DATA_BLOCK_ENCOD ING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATI ON_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVE R', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE = > '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'} 1 row(s) in 1.6670 seconds

The description of the configured table is:

> DESCRIPTION ENABLED '8reg', {CONFIGURATION => {'SPLIT_POLICY' => ' true org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy', 'MAX_FILESIZE' => '7381 97504'}}, {NAME => 'c1', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING = > 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SC OPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'N ONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', K EEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65 536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'} 1 row(s) in 1.6890 seconds

Thank you so much.

Comment: With HBase 1.0.0+ if setting the configuration in the hbase-site.xml file this problem doesn't appear. Not tested when overwriting the default configuration of the table in creation time.